# How to make a table cell merge two rows and two columns?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I need to do:

[image]

Red: two columns and two rows

Purple: two columns

Blue: two rows

yellow and white: normal cell

Here is my table so far:
[image]

Here is my html code:

```
      <body>
   <div id="container">
    <table id="board">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
     
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        
          </tr>

      </table>
    </div>

   </body>
```

Here is my css:

```
   *{
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #114B5F;
      text-align: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     padding-top: 2%;
   }
   #container {
       width: 800px;
       height: 500px;
       background: #E4FDE1;
       margin: 10px auto;
   }
  #board 
  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 
   border: 1px solid black;

 }
  td 
  {
     border: 1px solid black;

   }
```

Somehow the cell that is supposed to occupy two rows and two cells (Red in 1st image) it appears that is only occupying two rows even though the code says otherwise. Is it something on css? How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `table` for layout. The `table` tag should only be used for tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML did it already. To see this, do what follows. Comment the first

```
<td colspan="2"></td>
```

in the last row of your cell and substitute it with

```
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

At least as long as you have no content within any cell, the default width of the first two columns (merged by the consistent `colspan="2"` attributes) and the third column alone is the same so you do not notice the difference. I add a snippet just to show:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #114B5F;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 2%;
}
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #E4FDE1;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
#board {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.cblu{background-color:#0040ff}
td.clbl{background-color:#0080ff}
td.cred{background-color:#ff1a1a}
td.cwhi{background-color:#f8f8f8}
td.cyel{background-color:#ffff33}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container">
<table id="board">
  <tr>
    <td class="cblu" colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="cwhi"></td>
    <td class="cblu" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cred" colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td class="clbl" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td class="cyel"></td>
    <td class="cyel"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cyel"></td>
    <td class="cyel"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cblu"></td>
    <td class="cblu"></td>
    <!--<td class="cblu" colspan="2"></td>-->
    <td class="cwhi"></td>
    <td class="cblu" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Here I added the colors using some classes. I'd like to remark that no more edits to your DOM (html) is necessary to achieve what you want. But controlling responsively the width of the cells or columns of your table may not be trivial.